# What is the average number of turns in a game of Monopoly?

Tags: monopoly, probability, statistics

I can't find any research or public information on this topic.

<s>Edit: It was requested that I clarify the specifics of my request (e.g. the number of players and rule specifics). Rather than pigeon-hole people into a specific category (e.g. 3 players and tournament rules) I prefer to leave it open-ended, so that any and all relevant information will be provided.</s>

Edit edit: For the sake of simplicity, let's say that we are playing with 4 players and tournament rules.

Comment: You should provide some more information about the number of players you are playing with, the skill level and if you are using the correct rules or playing with different house rules. Those will help provide the information needed to answer this question.

Comment: @JoeW I appreciate you trying to help, but I actually intentionally left it broad. I had difficulty finding any information about this topic, so I'd rather cast the net wide rather than ask for a specific case

Comment: That doesn't help with providing an answer to your question though. As your question stands it can get many different answers which is the very definition of to broad on this site.

Comment: @Danny David Leybzon :
"I had difficulty finding any information about this topic..."
I have provided very specific information in my answer below; 
this answer also addresses your problem of estimating the number of game-turns for any number of players.

Answer (score 3):

Playing online against 3 computer opponents, one of my games would typically last 30-45 turns. I used the standard rules (i.e., no money on Free Parking, limited number of houses and hotels). Because it was me against computers, the games would take ~15 minutes to play.

Playing against human opponents would certainly extend the actual playing time, and may likely increase the number of turns for a game as well. House rules which inject money into the players' hands (e.g., money on Free Parking) will increase the number of turns, and thus playing time, too.

Comment: Do you have any sources for your information?

Comment: @JoeW as indicated in my answer, this is personal experience

Comment: I am not sure personal experience helps in this case as there are many variables that will impact how fast an electronic game will go.

Comment: Lacking anything more science-y I think this is a useful data point.

Answer (score 1):

According to a Ted-Ed article entitled
**Here's how to win at Monopoly, according to math experts**

> ... the average game of Monopoly takes about 30 turns per
>   competitor...

**Reference**

https://blog.ed.ted.com/2017/12/01/heres-how-to-win-at-monopoly-according-to-math-experts/

So the answer to your question is 120 turns (4 players times 30 turns/player)

By the way,

> the shortest possible game of Monopoly requires only four turns, nine
>   rolls of the dice...
>
> One player moves around the board very quickly, to buy Boardwalk and
>   Park Place, and places houses on them," Myers explained. "And the
>   other one ends up drawing a Chance card that sends them to Boardwalk,
>   and they don't have enough money to pay the rent with three houses,
>   and the game is over.

**Reference** «How To Win Monopoly In 21 Seconds»

https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2010/06/how_to_win_monopoly_in_21_seco.html